# How can I use parent relation attribute in sub query in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

```
$order_detail = Order::where([['user_id', $user->id], ['updated_at', '>', $updated_at]])
    ->with([
        'currency'  => function ($query) {
            $query->select('currency_code', 'currency_symbol', 'ex_rate_with_base');
        },
        'orderList' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'order_id', 'product_code', 'qty',
                DB::raw('(unit_price*orders.ex_rate_with_base) as unit_price_new'), 'status');
        },
    ])->get();
```

Please help,

How can I use the attribute `ex_rate_with_base` from order table in sub query.
I do not want to use `DB` query. Please solve it with eloquent.

Comment: Does this actually work with `DB`?

Answer (score 1):

I would have done it like this

Database Structure:

[image]

ModelCurrency.php

```
class ModelCurrency extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $table = 'currency';
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

ModelOrderList.php

```
class ModelOrderList extends Model{
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $table = 'order_list';
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

ModelOrderDetail.php

```
class ModelOrderDetail extends Model{
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $table = 'order_detail';
    protected $guarded = [];


    public function scopeOfUser($query, $user_id){
        return $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
    }

    public function scopeUpdatedAfter($query, $updated_at){
        return $query->where('updated_at', '>', $updated_at);
    }


    public function currency(){
        return $this->hasOne(ModelCurrency::class, 'id', 'currency_id');
    }

    public function order_lists(){
        return $this->hasMany(ModelOrderList::class, 'order_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Function in controller:

```
//imports
use App\ModelOrderDetail;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

public function prices() {
    $user_id = 1;
    $updated_at = Carbon::yesterday();

    $data = ModelOrderDetail::with('currency', 'order_lists')->ofUser($user_id)->updatedAfter($updated_at)->get();

    foreach ($data as $d){
        $base_rate = $d->currency->base_rate;
        foreach($d->order_lists as $o) $o->new_unit_price = $base_rate * $o->unit_price;
    }

    return response()->json($data);
};
```

Edit - Output : https://pastebin.com/i53PytSk

Comment: can you please share the tool that you was using to create such a beautiful database structure image?